# Add column of average in data frame using Python

Tags: python, datatable, grouping, average, data-cleaning

I want to create a new data frame consisting of sex, amount of children, price of insurance, and if an individual is a smoker or not. Below is an example of my data frame.

```
Sex    Children Insurance Smoker
Male      3      392.48    Yes
Male      6      782.68    Yes
Male      6      438.21    No 
Female    1      125.98    Yes
Female    1      58.32     No
Female    4      585.12    Yes
Female    4      356.12    No
```

So far I got this using the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(insurance).groupby(["sex", "children", "smoker"]).size()

#which outputs
sex      children   smoker
female   1          yes      1
         1          no       1
         4          yes      1
         4          no       1
male     3          yes      2
         6          yes      1
         6          no       1
```

How would I add a column of the average of insurance for each gender depending on how many children they have and if they smoke or not? I tried adding mean("insurance") but got an error, of course. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(["Sex", "Children", "Smoker"],as_index=False)["Insurance"].mean()

#output

    Sex Children Smoker Insurance
0   Female  1     No    58.32
1   Female  1     Yes   125.98
2   Female  4     No    356.12
3   Female  4     Yes   585.12
4   Male    3     Yes   392.48
5   Male    6     No    438.21
6   Male    6     Yes   782.68
```

Is that what you want?

```
     Sex       Children Smoker  size mean
0     Female       1    No      1   58.32
1     Female       1    Yes     1   125.98
2     Female       4    No      1   356.12
3     Female       4    Yes     1   585.12
4       Male       3    Yes     1   392.48
5       Male       6    No      1   438.21
6       Male       6    Yes     1   782.68
```

Comment: Yes! But I'm getting an error, unfortunately, "as_index=False only valid with DataFrame" is what is showing up.

Comment: you should name your data correctly. and btw i wouldnt recommend grouping on all your values. basically your mean is not a real mean if you group your table on everything because the size is 1 in every category

Comment: free one of the values you are grouping on to get a real mean

Comment: @imnguyen isnt ur data a dataframe from the beginning ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the beginning. The only value that was different was the "insurance" on my data frame. I kept reading it as "insurance" rather than "charges". The data frame is rather large so only wanted to put a small bit of it. I apologize if I didn't provide enough information to paint a more better picture of what I had asked for. But each column has value under "size" would be more than 20, for sure, though. But I do thank you for the help!

Comment: @imnguyen no problem, if my answer is good enough mark it as answer to remove it from feed.

Comment: Got it, hey, do you mind if I get your opinion on this? So I wanted to plot my data by sex depending on amount of children whether they smoked on or not in relation to the average price of insurance. Do you think it would be better to plot it  using sex (with and without kids) in relation to average price of insurance?

Comment: @imnguyen not gona lie to u its pretty late right now. if you post this as a new question someone might answer it , apologies